# Opção para "Pedir a retirada do seu voto"

Tags: debate

Frequentemente, no SO, em geral, eu tenho enfrentado o mesmo caso várias vezes, que se define no seguinte:

Alguém posta uma pergunta, e você acha boa, e da +1 vote, passa alguns minutos e alguém comenta uma coisa que você não tinha percebido mas achou isso mais do que motivo pra retirar seu voto, porém você tenta retirar e não pode até que a questão seja editada, porém na maioria dos casos ela nunca é editada, e você fica com aquele voto ali pra sempre, mesmo querendo com todas as forças retira-lo.

Ou ao contrario: alguém postou uma resposta que você achou ruim e deu downvote, porém alguem comentou algo que fez te enchergar de uma forma diferente e você pensou: "Droga mas isso tá muito certo!" você tenta retirar o downvote, e não consegue, porque o cara nunca mais vai editar a resposta.

Eu acho que isso seria uma Maravilha, e quem sabe poderia ter uma fila de "Revisão" para esses "Pedidos para retirar voto" assim aumentando a responsabilidade dos usuários em manter o SO nos trinques, aumentando a confiabilidade dos Votos investidos em uma pergunta, tornando-a auto explicativa se ela está ruim ou boa, pelos Votos.

> O ser humano é passível a errar, pois não é perfeito e por natureza temos a indecisão carregada em nossas costas.

**Se temos a possibilidade de desfazer um voto de fechamento, de editar uma pergunta, de editar um comentário, de excluir um comentário, porque não podemos desfazer nossos votos??**

Pois os Votos devem expressar a opinião do povo aqui do SO. São a função deles, votos errôneos só dificultariam essa expressão.

Concordam ou discordam?

Comment: O único problema desta pergunta aqui é que é algo que afeta toda a rede. Não podemos ter o engine funcionando aqui diferente do resto. Por isso qualquer que seja a decisão aqui, ela será inócua. Só no MSO é possível conseguir que alguma mudança no engine seja feita. Se não souber inglês alguém poderia ajudar para postar essa solicitação lá.

Comment: Eu posso, porém quero saber a opinião de outras pessoas antes de fazer isto

Comment: Estou surpreso pelo fato de esta ideia ter -2 sendo que é uma ideia ótima.

Comment: Ninguém é obrigado a votar no que não sabe e/ou não entende, então é importante pensar e analisar antes de votar, e votar no que está sabendo. Se esse problema acontece com frequência com você, e não muito com outros usuários, TALVEZ seja melhor uma repensada no modo como você usa o sistema (mas vamos ver as opiniões dos outros, de qualquer forma).

Answer (score 10):

Meus argumentos contra isso:

- A votação faz parte da história de uma pergunta. Desfazer votos de tal forma seria alterar a história das perguntas.
- Tornar o voto efêmero reduziria seu valor. Não o valor de reputação, que não passa de um  contador, mas sim seu valor como validação por parte da comunidade sobre a corretude ou erro de uma afirmação.
- Isso abriria espaço para situações no mínimo inusitadas. Uma técnica ou tecnologia corrente pode ser usada para resolver um problema hoje, e respostas que a utilizem podem ter muitos votos positivos. Se forem questões de referência e alto ranking no Google, ano que vem as mesmas respostas boas e corretas podem se transformar em respostas erradas e com muitos votos negativos.
- Já houveram casos no Stack Exchange onde pessoas mal intencionadas davam downvote em todas as respostas de uma pergunta nova, para que sua própria resposta ficasse em uma posição mais alta na página, de forma a atrair mais atenção. Depois de ganharem alguns votos positivos, desfaziam os votos negativos nas respostas dos outros para não deixar rastros nem arcarem com o custo dos votos negativos. Isso com um limite de desfazimento de votos de cinco minutos. Imagine o que essas pessoas não fariam se não houvesse limite.

Comment: Agora sim eu recebi um argumento decente, estou pensando acerca disso tudo que você falou e concordo com algumas coisas e outras não, das quais: `"A votação faz parte da história de uma pergunta"` completamente discordo, pois comentários e flags e edições "que podem ser disfeitas" também fazem parte do historico, e porque o voto seria diferente?

Comment: `"Tornar o voto efêmero reduziria seu valor. Não o valor de reputação, que não passa de um contador, mas sim seu valor como validação por parte da comunidade sobre a corretude ou erro de uma afirmação.` falando isso você está indo pro lado meu ponto de vista, você está afirmando que a minha idéia seria melhor, porque com certeza com isto as perguntas estariam muito mais corretamente votadas, porque respostas ruins em alguns casos podem estar bem votadas erroneamente, porém com a desfeita de votos errôneos esta taxa iria diminuir tornando a resposta melhor classificada.

Comment: "`Uma técnica ou tecnologia corrente pode ser usada para resolver um problema hoje, e respostas que a utilizem podem ter muitos votos positivos. Se forem questões de referência e alto ranking no Google, ano que vem as mesmas respostas boas e corretas podem se transformar em respostas erradas e com muitos votos negativos."` Nisto eu concordo completamente com você, me abriu os olhos pra algo que eu não havia pensado, porém a minha solução estaria boa ainda, mas eu teria que modificar minha idéia colocando um limite para desfazer o voto em no máximo 48 horas, estaria de bom tamanho :)

Comment: `"Depois de ganharem alguns votos positivos, desfaziam os votos negativos nas respostas dos outros para não deixar rastros nem arcarem com o custo dos votos negativos."` Discordo completamente, pois, a desfeita de votos não deve voltar sua reputação, você deve perder -2 pra sempre ao clicar em downvote, mesmo depois de desfeito, e isso de "não deixar rastros" não tem nada haver, pois há pessoas com acesso a histórico completo de perguntas detalhado, que poderiam ver o que foi feito facilmente, não é ? :)

Comment: outra coisa: `"dar downvote para subir minha resposta"` não poderia ser feito porque você teria que pedir para retirar seu voto depois `"retirar seu rastro"` e mediante ao argumento utilizado em descrição as pessoas iriam aceitar que tirasse ou não.

Answer (score 9):

Não acho que criar uma nova linha de revisão seja bom.

Um pergunta que está votada fora do que ela merece (para cima ou para baixo) tende a encontrara sua votação correcta com o tempo e os votos da comunidade, por isso não vejo que um voto individual faça a diferença.

Existe já uma margem de erro, uns minutos nos quais dá para retirar o voto. Cada vez que a pergunta/resposta é editada é também possível retirar ou mudar a direcção do voto.

Comment: você não ve "1 voto" fazendo a diferença, e 2? e 3? e 50?

Comment: Mas votar 50 vezes errado, não é bem votar errado... (no caso da mesma pergunta)

Comment: @PauloRoberto se 50 votos estiverem errados no mesmo post então têm algo de errado no post e precisa de um comentário, não de um voto. Se a mesma pessoa vota errado em 50 perguntas, então deve abrandar e não puxar o gatilho tão rápido.

Comment: porém temos que pensar em pequenas ações que se tornam grandes mediante a quantidade de pessoas, se uma pessoa joga o lixo no chão está tudo bem para você? pra mim não pois isso vai ser repetido por muitas e muitas pessoas!

Comment: @PauloRoberto, no SOen já respondí a mais de 700 posts e lí outros tantos. Respondí aqui com a minha opinião pois não vejo que seja um padrão de erro. Você pode sempre deixar um comentário no post a pedir para editar ou a justificar.

Comment: claro mas nada garante que o cara vai fazer isso @Sergio não da pra viver com incertezas